# Fetch records from different tables using array of ids in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Suppose i have a array of ids like below.

```
@all_ids=[1,2,3,4]
```

My requirement is using very last id i will fetch records from one table(i.e-User) and i will fetch records from another table(i.e-Payment) using rest of the ids in an array.In the below method i will do this operation.

> users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def update
@all_ids=[1,2,3,4]
end
end
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You can get last element from @all_ids using `@all_ids.last` so you can use last id to get record from user table then you can use this to get rest of ids in array `@all_ids - [@all_ids.last]`

Answer (score 2):

The pop method returns the last element in the array. It is a destructive method in that it alters the contents of the array. The array will now hold all the values minus the last one.

```
user = User.find(@all_ids.pop)
payments = Payment.find(@all_ids)
```

Comment: I like your answer more - I completely forgot you can pass an array into `#find`

Comment: @margo : I need to fetch records as per all ids without last id in array.How can i make your line-2 accordingly.

Comment: Experiment with pop in the console and you will see that once you have used pop on the array, the array is altered and will not contain the last element. E.g. run all_ids.pop - it will return 4. Then run all_ids - it will return [1,2,3]. That is why it is called destructive. As long as you don't mind  the array being altered, then you can use it, though many would not recommend it for that very reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
user = User.find(@all_ids.pop)
payments = Payment.find(@all_ids)
```